# Simple LISP question

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm just learning LISP and i am having trouble doing the following:

```
; return ":h :i"
(defun get-char() 
  (loop for char across "ab" 
        collect (concatenate 'string ":" (string char))))

; plist
(defun get-list() (list :a "1" :b "2"))

; I cannot get this to work 
; <-- returns all null, cannot get plist values :-(
(loop for x in (get-char) 
      collect (getf (get-list) x))

; this works fine...
(loop for x in '(:a :b) 
      collect (getf (get-list) x))
```

I know im close, but i am just missing something.

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Tip: might want to come up with a more descriptive title than "Simple LISP question" next time.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Change the `get-char` function to return a list of keywords from the characters:**

```
(defun get-char() 
  (loop 
    for char across "ab" 
    collect (intern (string-upcase char) :keyword)))
```

Evaluating `(get-char)` => `(:A :B)`. Furthermore:

```
(loop for x in (get-char) collect (getf (get-list) x))
```

=>

```
("1" "2")
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted - seems a bit cryptic to me, but i am just starting on LISP - it make sense tho :-) - THANK YOU!